# Spring boot @Scheduler not working on tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, tomcat8

I have a @Scheduled method which runs without a problem when I build my Spring Boot application using embedded tomcat. But when i build my project in .war and deploy it using tomcat v8, it seem like scheduler not trigger. Other functions working great just this scheduler not trigger on my server.

```
@Component
public class DeleteUser {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Autowired
private UserAuthoritiesService userAuthService;

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DeleteUser.class);

private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

//(cron="second, minute, hour, day of month, month, day(s) of week")
@Scheduled(cron="0 0 8 * * *", zone="Asia/Kuala_Lumpur")
public void schedulerDeleteUser() {

    List<User> ls = userService.getAllInactiveUser3Day(new Date());

    try {
        if(ls.size()>0) {

            for(User user: ls) {
                userService.updateStatusAccount(false, user.getId());
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    logger.info("Scheduler run at {}", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
  }
}
```

Comment: have you @EnableScheduling added this annotation ?

Comment: yes..i already enable it. it working fine if using embedded server in spring boot. but if i maven install n export it file in tomcat. that scheduler seem like not working

Comment: Hi @FlyingTurtle, did you managed to sort this out eventually? I'm facing exactly the same problem right now, hence the question.

Comment: @ADi3ek still no hope.. if u found the answer please do let me know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem: everything working fine on built-in tomcat server but not 
when I've deployed .war file into production. I've tried a few things to solve it (don't remember exactly which particular one worked) and eventually I've ended up with the following:

1. I have dedicated scheduler configuration class:

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableScheduling
   @EnableAsync
   public class SchedulerConfiguration implements SchedulingConfigurer {

       private final int POOL_SIZE = 2;
       private final String THREAD_NAME_PREFIX = "task-scheduler-";

       @Override
       public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduledTaskRegistrar) {
           ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();

           threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(POOL_SIZE);
           threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix(THREAD_NAME_PREFIX);
           threadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize();

           scheduledTaskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(threadPoolTaskScheduler);
       }
   }
   ```

   I guess, what's most important above are `@EnableScheduling` and `@EnableAsync` annotations (I didn't had the 2nd one before)
2. Last but not least, I have noticed that my main application class wasn't extending `SpringBootServletInitializer` so I have fixed that too:

   ```
   public class SpringBootApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           SpringApplication.run(MarketplaceMonitorApplication.class, args);
       }
   }
   ```

   Without it, application started but `@Scheduling` wasn't working.. or I fixed that earlier and forget :-) Anyway, please make sure you have it! ;-)

Now everything works on the production as expected.